# Remove script via xml

Tags: layout, xml, magento-1.14

I got the following script loaded in the head:

```
<script src="https://selfservice.robinhq.com/external/robin/XXXX.js" async="async"></script>
```

What is the correct way (syntax) to remove it on every category page (syntax in the local.xml)?

```
<reference name="content"> 
    (remove method..........)
</reference>
```

Magento version 1.14.3.7

Comment: is it 3rd party javascript?

Comment: Yes, it is; so it's loaded externally

Comment: from where its loading? I mean which file ? from somewhere its calling into Magento

Answer (score 1):

try below code for Magento 2.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="https://selfservice.robinhq.com/external/robin/XXXX.js"/>
</head>
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css

Comment: Hi; Thank you for the answer; I want to keep it in the head and only removed in every category page :)

Comment: Then you should put this code in `catalog_category_view` XML file

Comment: OP was asking about 1.14